# How to Make a For-Each Loop Run Backwards

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

I have written a small script in VBA which checks the value of a cell in a given range against a list.  If the cell values match a value in the list it is kept, else it is deleted.  I was wondering how I could make it run backward, as running it forwards creates issues.  I have researched this somewhat and I have tried appending 'Step -1' to the end of the line which begins the for loop, but this doesn't work in this case.

```
Set Rng = Range("A9:V9")
For Each cell In Rng
    If Not myList.Exists(cell.Value) Then
        cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, probably some for-loop like this one would be enough:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set rng = Range("A9:V9")

    For cnt = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Cells(rng.Row, cnt) = 23
        Stop
    Next

End Sub
```

I have put `Stop` so you can see which cell is referred. Once you hit the `Stop`, continue further with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Richard, you're entirely right that the "Step -1" approach would be the right solution in this case. You simply have to change the variable references around to work with the loop.

For example:

```
Set Rng = Range("A9:V9")
For i = rng.rows.count to 1 step -1
    for j = rng.columns.count to 1 step -1
        if not myList.Exists(rng.cells(i, j).value) then
           rng.cells(i, j).entirecolumn.delete ' This probably won't work, but you get the idea.
        end if
    next j
next i
```