# Make shape FADE IN

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

This is gonna sound really stupid ( I can't believe I was not able to do this!) but I just can't get my head around! I have a nice bit of code that makes objects fade out, but I cannot make them fade in!

Can someone please help?

This is what I have to make it fade out (then it disappears at the end)

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("linha1")
    For i = 0 To 100
        .Fill.Transparency = i / 100
        Delay = 0.001
        starttime = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While Timer - starttime < Delay
    Next i

End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes("linha1").Visible = False`:
```

Comment: Could it be `For i = 100 to 0 Step -1` ? If yes, then this question might actually be a duplicate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50684927/8597922)

Comment: Viktor K,
That is a north to follow, however, it is making it appear all of a sudden ignoring the transparency loop, trying to work a way around with your input.

Comment: Is it because you put the shape in then adjust its transparency?  Can the object be inserted with a starting transparency of 1?

Comment: @VictorK I think you're right. Your solution or having `.Fill.Transparency = 1 - i / 100` will achieve what OP likely wants. Both amounts to counting down instead of up.

Comment: It makes sense, it worked well now, it´s just a question of adjust the time of delay and that solved! I guess that was answer by both, @Viktor K and Forward Ed. Please click answer so I can properly award you guys

Comment: @roca I am glad it helped! I would say, that since it turned out to be a duplicate you can just close question with the dupe target I posted.